# Watson Visual Recognition Classifier taking hours to retrain

Tags: classification, ibm-watson, visual-recognition

12 hours ago I made a request for retrain for visual recognition, sending 180 new images in zip files, the command was executed successfully, but so far the status of the classifier is like "retraining", can I cancel it in any way?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this does happen sometimes, and the API does not provide a way to fix it currently.   You can open a support ticket with IBM Cloud and include the classifier ID and your instance ID (which shows up as the owner field in the result of GET /classifiers/{cid})